# Returning the list of classes defined inside a package using inspect

Tags: python

I have the below module structure:

[image: Directory structure of my code]

The code inside `Person.py` is :

```
class person:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def displayage(self):
        print ("Your age is {0}".format(self.age))
```

Inside `Vechile.py` is:

```
class vechile:
    def __init__(self,type):
        self.type = type

    def display_type(self):
        print ("Your vechile type is {}".format(self.type))
```

Inside `__init__.py`:

```
pass
```

And inside `Test.py` I want to know the class names defined inside `Person.py` and `Vechile.py`.

```
import inspect
from Fetch import Vechile
from Fetch import Person

modules = ['Vechile','Person']
for module in modules:
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if inspect.isclass(name):
            print (obj)

v = Vechile.vechile("Auto")
print (v)
```

The answer that I get is only this:

`<Fetch.Vechile.vechile object at 0x0000000000DD0C18>`

Where am I going wrong? How can I get the list of classes defined inside `Person` and `Vechile`?

Comment: Shouldn't `Vechile` be a `Vehicle`?

Comment: Offtopic, but your naming is inconsistent, why `displayage` and `display_type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently passing a module name as a string to `inspect.getmembers` here:

```
modules = ['Vechile','Person']
for module in modules:
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module):
        ...
```

This will be looking at the members of a *string instance*, not the members of a module.  To find the members of a module, **give it a module**.

```
modules = [Vechile, Person]
for module in modules:
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module, inspect.isclass):
        # no need to check if is class here
        ...
```

Comment: Don't think it is working. I did as you told. I still have the same output.

Comment: @SubhayanBhattacharya Probably because in your original code you checked if `name` was a class, rather than `obj` ...

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed your mistakes.

Person.py

```
class person():
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def displayage(self):
        return("Your age is {0}".format(self.age))
```

Vechile.py

```
class vechile():
    def __init__(self,type):
        self.type = type

    def display_type(self):
        return("Your vechile type is {}".format(self.type))
```

Test.py(remains the same)

```
import inspect
from Fetch import Vechile
from Fetch import Person

modules = ['Vechile','Person']
for module in modules:
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if inspect.isclass(name):
            print (obj)

v = Vechile.vechile.display_type("Auto")
print (v)
```

Comment: Not working in this way too ! I am sorry , i still have the same output.

Answer (score 0):

There's two things wrong in `main.py`. Here's a fixed version with the changes indicated:

```
import inspect
from Fetch import Vechile
from Fetch import Person

modules = [Vechile, Person]  # changed
for module in modules:
    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if inspect.isclass(obj):  # changed
            print(obj)

v = Vechile.vechile("Auto")
print(v)
```